# rails postmark_mailer doesn't work. I get a template id (APInputError) missing, when I use default template it works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I want to send a welcome e mail to new users of my app. If I use default one it works, however when I edit the email layout I get an APIerror. TemplateID associated with this request not found or missing.

I follow the gem documentation to the letter https://github.com/scienceexchange/postmark_mailer

and my code looks like this:

```
class UserMailer < PostmarkMailer::Base
 def welcome_email(user)
  @user = user
  @url  = 'http://listy.club/users/sign_in'
  mail(
  to: @user.email,
  from:'support@listy.club',
  template_id: 8043061,
  template_model: {
    username: @user.username,
    company_name: "Listy",
    product_name: "Listy",
    action_url: "http://www.listy.club/users/sign_in",
    login_url: "http://www.listy.club/users/sign_in",
    support_email: "support@listy.club",
    help_url: "help_url_Value",
    company_address: "Germany 10439 Berlin"
   }
  )
 end
end

PostmarkMailer.configure do |config|
config.api_key = "ce14d1d0-****-***-****-****cf08e3e" # required
config.default_delivery_queue = :mailers # defaults to :default
end
```

Does anyone see an error here? Would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure about the template_id?  As you are including it in the call, it appears that the postmark api cannot find the template with the id `8043061`.

Comment: That's the error message I get yeah.. but I don't get it because when I do the API call from the Terminal it works.. I feel like it's the format of my def welcome_email method .. or the way I store the API key?

Comment: Omg it was really the template id .. That was the first thing I checked obviously but somehow I must have overseen it. Thanks anyway :))